# Can I play Minecraft with my 360 friends on an Xbox one emulating minecraft 360?

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console, backwards-compatibility

Is it possible to play Minecraft with my Xbox 360 friends online using backward compatibility on Xbox one?

So I would buy Minecraft 360 , put it in my Xbox one, can I play it with my Xbox 360 friends online with Xbox live?

Comment: If you can fit 359 other people in the room...

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Xbox One, you can't play Minecraft with Xbox 360 users.

This is even if you have Xbox Live Gold. Sorry, man.

However there are some games (EG: Borderlands 2) which are compatible for both consoles.

Answer (score -1):

If your game runs on the console, then I think I know the rest.

So you need **Xbox Live GOLD** first of all, then you have to select Multiplayer on the home screen. Once that is done, you can select the server, or do whatever. That should work.

Also, If your friends don't have **Xbox Live GOLD** you can't play with them.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I don't believe the question is about needing XBLG, but rather if the X360 version on XB1 works with someone using the X360 on original hardware as well.